# Can I make a live site WITHOUT Google indexing it?

Tags: url

If you have a dev. site and do not want Google to index it, how would you do this? Thanks.

Comment: Learn about `robots.txt`

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard

Comment: Don't make it publicly accessible if you don't want the public accessing it.

Comment: [robots.txt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard) is just a directive, which a crawler may not listen to. So to make 100% inaccessible to the crawler (or anyone) giving access only to authorized user is the only way...

Comment: Matt Ball - I do want is publicly accessible, but do not want Google indexing it. I have just been reading about the robots.txt file thanks for that, and also you can request from Google that is it not indexable. Think it's called a site takedown request?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I use that method that you must login before you see anything. You can put some meta tags put it will be useless Google finds it.

Comment: What do you mean "You can put some meta tags put it will be useless Google finds it."?

Answer (score 1):

you should create a `robots.txt` in your webroot where `index.html` is with this content.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

and in your `index.html` you should put this lines:

```
<head>
...
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
...
</head>
```